# How to wait until data is received and fully processed, before sending the next set of data request?

Tags: java, android, threadpool, wait, synchronized

I found a few answers, 'wait, notify, synchronized, thread etc' but not really sure how to apply it into my code. In `Trigger()` method, I want it to wait until `dataACK = true` before executing the next `SendCommand`.

```
private void ReceiveData(byte[] rData) {
    // ReceiveData() is called when there's data received
    ...
    ...
    ...
    dataACK = true;
}

private void SendCommand(String instruction){

    ...
    ...
    ...
    dataACK = false;
    OutToPort(instruction);             
    // OutToPort() will cause ReceiveData() to execute 
    // when data is received a few ms later
}

private void Trigger(){
    SendCommand("Command1");
    // here it waits until dataACK is set to true

    SendCommand("Command2");
    // here it waits until dataACK is set to true

    SendCommand("Command3");
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Thank you @John Saunders. or should I not thank you.. ;) Anyway, any ideas to help me out?

Comment: If I had an idea, and if I wanted to "help you out", then I could have done so. Since I chose not to "help you out", you may presume that I either had no idea, or else did not want to help you out in that manner. I _did_ help you out by removing fluff from your question, making it more likely that you'll receive good answers, and even _more_ likely that your question will get upvotes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

wait() method means you wait until the resource is not locked. and notify() means you are now going out from the critical section and release resources.
So if you want to wait until one data is sent, you have to go into critical section before you send messages and go out from critical section after you sent them all.
I think you have to call wait() at the first of each call of SendCommand("content") and call notify function in the end of SendCommand method.

Comment: Hmm... I read your code again and I guess you are not using multithreading. You are just calling SendCommand method three times in sequence. then you cannot use wait() and notify() because wait() method waits until another thread calls notify() method.

Comment: Maybe you can use 'synchronized' keyword in front of void SendCommand() because if you use this keyword for a method, then if the method is executed, no other thread can be executed at the same time. I didn't try it, so If you try it, plz show me and others the result :)

Comment: I did try that. It didn't help. SendCommand() is not what I wait for, but the ReceiveData(byte[] rData) to set the flag dataACK = true;

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Then you have to wait after you call OutToPort method and call notify() in the end of ReceiveData method. 
If you don't want to use wait() and notify(), you can use busy waiting with while statement. It is not a recommended way, but will be much easier.

Comment: I could not figure out how to let the "system" do the background work for me to achieve what I wanted, by using the built-in methods & keywords such as Thread, synchronized etc.. I believe it can be done. It's just that no one is really willing to help except for you @user3934037. I thank you so much my friend! Anyway, I finally got it done! I used my own tricks to solve it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CountDownLatch for example (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)